# MySQL SELECT multiple/all max values in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I get this table:

```
MyTable
+----+-------+
| ID | count |
+----+-------+
| a  | 2     |
| b  | 6     |
| c  | 4     |
| d  | 6     |
| e  | 2     |
+----+-------+
```

Now I want this back:

```
Result
+----+-------+
| ID | count |
+----+-------+
| b  | 6     |
| d  | 6     |
+----+-------+
```

I want the IDs that have the most counted values. So if there are multiple maximum values, I want them all. Also I don't know if there *will* be multiple values and if there are, how many it will be.

Comment: Looks like similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: Just for curiosity: why is this question downvoted? It seems to be a valid question. Is it because no tries are posted from the OP? Or because there are already similar posts and answers at StackExchange?

Comment: @Marc That one does indeed look similar, but it doesn't answer my question. I already stumbled upon that one before posting my question.

Comment: @wumpz Believe me I tried, I'm struggling with this since yesterday. Else I wouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the greatest value inside the subquery. Eg,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   count = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(count) 
            FROM    MyTable
        )
```

Comment: This answer is the most straightforward and the most elegant one.

Comment: @QuantumHive [*Join vs. sub-query*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) this will give you the better idea but performance can be measured by explain plan of query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  Id, count
FROM MyTable
WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable where count in (select max(count) from MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable 
where 
  count= (select max(count) from mytable )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ID, count from table where count in (
    select distinct count from table order by Value desc limit 1
) order by count desc
```

You requested only top row but by this query if you want top 3 you easily can change it to `limit 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead of using subquery

```
SELECT *,t.max_count 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(`count`) max_count FROM Table1 ) t
HAVING t1.`count`=t.max_count
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abb0b/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, max(count) as max_count 
  from table1 where count=(select max(count) from table1)
group by id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abb0b/9